# how to get day of the week only if entered date is falling between last monday

Tags: c#, date

i am trying to get day of the week only if entered date is falling between last Monday to current date i.e if today is 30/10/14 the output should be Thursday else just show date entered 
here is what i am trying

```
DateTime aa = Convert.ToDateTime(rr.detail);
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(aa).Days < 7)
{
    // but this is not i am looking for i want only if aa 
    // is falling between last monday and less than 7 days
}
```

so any idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the steps I'd take are:

> 1) Get the date of the previous Monday
>
> 2) Get the user's date
>
> 3) Check if the user's date is after the previous Monday (in which case
>   show the day)

```
//Get the date of the previous Monday
DateTime prevMonday = DateTime.Now;
while(prevMonday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
      prevMonday = prevMonday.AddDays(-1);


//get user's date 
DateTime aa = Convert.ToDateTime(rr.detail);

//check if the user's date is after the Monday
if (aa > prevMonday && aa <= DateTime.Now.Date)    
    Console.WriteLine(aa.DayOfWeek);
else
    Console.WriteLine(aa);
```

Comment: i want to just show dayoftheweek if userdate is falling in current week starting from monday in your code i took example of date 24/10/14 but as it not falling on this week starting from monday it should go in else category hope you understood my problem? @keyboardP

Comment: I just tried it and 24/10/14 does go in the `else` block.